# Handle features of different dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I have some previous knowledge about classification, however am now struggling in understanding how classification algorithms can deal with features with different dimensions. Up to now I have only used a feature vector consisting of scalars, where each scalar had one feature for itself (e.g. the variance of the data). Now, in my current problem, I want to use features that are either scalars as before or vectors (or histograms) themselves. I would hence have a feature vector looking similar to this:

```
feature_vector = { 2, {3,4,5}, 5, {6,7,8,9}, ...}
```

Can the standard classification algorithms deal with this? For SVMs maybe I could devise a kernel that works on sets of vectors, but e.g. for Random Forests I don't see how I can use such a feature vector. What is the general approach in this kind of situation? Maybe you would simply concatenate the vectors (i.e. remove the `{`)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I think you could embed sub-features into the feature-vector (flatten it, so to speak), or preprocess sub-features in a preliminary step to produce a signature value (distinctive scalar) for every sub-feature vector.

Comment: I think you can just concatenate all features to one vector also take a look at vector quantization.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. Most people just build a flat vector "removing" the '{'.